# VS 2008 no debug on remote call to local machine (IIS)

Tags: web-services, visual-studio-2008, remote-debugging

I developed a webservice that I'm testing on my development machine using IIS. If I call the webservice from the local machine (`http://localhost/BaanWeb/service1.asmx`, click on the webservice) the debugger hits a breakpoint.

If I call the same webservice from a remote machine (`http://ipaddress/baanweb/service1.asmx`, click the webservice) the webservice is called, I see a value being returned, but the breakpoint is not hit, so I cannot debug.

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach to the remote server (at "ipaddress"): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/233w9kd4(v=vs.90).aspx

This article may also help (even though it is asp.net specific): http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38132/Remote-IIS-Debugging-Debug-your-ASP-NET-Applicatio

Comment: Hi Grady, Tanks for your answer, but the webservice is running locally (on the dev-machine with IIS). I did try attaching, but it made no difference.

Comment: Ah.  I missed read.  A few questions/suggestions:
1. If you click "[http://ipaddress/BaanWeb/service1.asmx](http://ipaddress/BaanWeb/service1.asmx)" ON YOUR LOCAL MACHINE  does the break point get hit?
2. In some cases, you may need to clean, rebuild, redeploy to assure
all the dlls are up to date (not likely, but just a suggestion).
3. The other option is to use the "big hammer" and put a "System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();" in your web service code
and call webservice from remote machine a. make sure it breaks and b. attach with VS to debug.